# Minimum Spanning Tree in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree

This is a ACM-ICPC practicing problem: http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=975. And the basic idea is to find the shortest weight of a minimum spanning tree. And I tried to solve it with Kruskal algorithm. I tested it myself and it seems to be working fine. However, when I submit it onto the uva online judge, the result is "wrong answer". Could any body see where is not correct? Thanks!

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
//import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
//import java.math.*;

public class Main  {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, IOException {

        BufferedReader cin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));  
        int numOfCases = Integer.parseInt(cin.readLine());

        while (numOfCases > 0) {
            cin.readLine();
            int numOfPoints = Integer.parseInt(cin.readLine());
            List<Points> listOfPoints = new ArrayList<Points>();
            List<Edge> listOfEdges = new ArrayList<Edge>();

            double inkUsed = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < numOfPoints; i++) {
                String[] tokens = cin.readLine().split(" ");
                Points point = new Points(Double.parseDouble(tokens[0]),Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]));
                listOfPoints.add(point);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < listOfPoints.size(); i++) {
                for (int j = i+1; j < listOfPoints.size(); j++) {
                    Edge edge = new Edge(listOfPoints.get(i), listOfPoints.get(j));
                    listOfEdges.add(edge);
                }
            }

            Collections.sort(listOfEdges);

            for (Edge e: listOfEdges) {

                Points pointA = null;
                Points pointB = null;

                // Find pointA and pointB in the list "listOfPoints"
                for (int i = 0; i < listOfPoints.size(); i++) {
                    if (listOfPoints.get(i).x == e.A.x && listOfPoints.get(i).y == e.A.y) {
                        pointA = listOfPoints.get(i);
                    }
                    if (listOfPoints.get(i).x == e.B.x && listOfPoints.get(i).y == e.B.y) {
                        pointB = listOfPoints.get(i);
                    }
                }

                Points rootOfA = findSet(pointA);
                Points rootOfB = findSet(pointB);

                if (rootOfA.x != rootOfB.x || rootOfA.y != rootOfB.y){  //add this edge
                    //System.out.println( "[" + "(" + pointA.x +"," + pointA.y+"); (" + pointB.x +"," + pointB.y+")"+ "]");
                    inkUsed += e.weight;
                    rootOfA.parent = rootOfB;
                }
            }

            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00"); 
            System.out.println(df.format(inkUsed));
            numOfCases--;
        }
    }

    public static Points findSet(Points A) {
        Points rootOfA = A;

        while (rootOfA.parent != null) {
            rootOfA = rootOfA.parent;
        }
        return rootOfA;
    }
}

class Points {  

    public double x;
    public double y;
    public Points parent = null;

    Points (double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

class Edge implements Comparable<Edge> {

    Points A;
    Points B;
    double weight;

    Edge (Points var1, Points var2) {
        A = var1;
        B = var2;
        weight = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((A.x-B.x), 2) + Math.pow((A.y-B.y), 2));
    }

    public String toString() {
        return Double.toString(weight);
    }

    public int compareTo(Edge anotherEdge) {
        if (this.weight < anotherEdge.weight) {
            return -1;
        } else if (this.weight == anotherEdge.weight) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: MST, can be solved by 4 known solutions but only 3 are relevant for non parallel computation. **Prim**, **Kruskal** and **Inverse Kruskal**.

All 3 are solved using `BFS\DFS`.

With Prime the solution is using the Vertex in order to solve this issue. While with Kruskal the solution is to Sort the edges weight and then to check for non circular connection, otherwise to remove it else add it.

Comment: I can't, at first sight, see any major fault, but I have two remarks. First, what you're doing looks more like Kruskal than Dijkstra (you sort the edges and always looking for the cheapest one that won't form a circuit). Which in itself is OK, since Dijkstra doesn't have to find the MST anyway. Second remark is: is the // Find pointA and pointB in the list "listOfPoints" part necessary? Can't you use the Points from Edge? From what I see it's still the same object and it would make the code a bit simpler.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, this is a Kruskal algorithm.